# API Gateway (IB) not working in Linux (interactive brokers)

Tags: java, api-gateway, interactive-brokers

After installation in Ubuntu, is imposible to connecto the API Gateway of iteractive brokes through localhost. When trying to reach https://localhost:5000 (using the browser or curl) I get

```
2023-08-09 08:25:49.763 [SF] ERROR [JTS-SocketListener-55] - Client disconnected before version was sent.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection terminated
    at jextend.bg.a(bg.java:820)
    at jextend.bg.b(bg.java:371)
    at jextend.cG.b(cG.java:379)
    at jextend.bg.q(bg.java:964)
    at jextend.eC.c(eC.java:480)
    at jextend.eC.run(eC.java:299)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2023-08-09 08:25:49.871 [SF] WARN  [JTS-SocketListener-55] - Error
twslaunch.jutils.SLogging$Warning: API client version is missing.
    at twslaunch.jutils.au.B(au.java:287)
    at jextend.eC.run(eC.java:302)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2023-08-09 08:25:55.322 [SF] INFO  [JTS-DeadlockMonitor-2] - Memory:total=786,432KB free=682,569KB HeapUsage: Max=786,432KB used=101,814KB committed=203,776KB NonHeapUsage: Max=0KB used=131,297KB committed=134,528KB
2023-08-09 08:25:56.325 [SF] INFO  [JTS-DeadlockMonitor-2] - CPU:cur=0.10% avg=0.76% 30 min avg=0.76% 10 min avg=0.76% 5 min avg=0.61% 1 min avg=0.12%
GC:called=12 times CPU used=0.03%
Finalizer:cur=0.00% avg=0.00% 30 min avg=0.00% 10 min avg=0.00% 5 min avg=0.00% 1 min avg=0.00%
Threads Count:curr live=62 curr daemon=28
2023-08-09 08:26:06.474 [SF] INFO  [JTS-SocketListener-55] - State: STOP, IsAPI: NO
2023-08-09 08:26:06.475 [SF] ERROR [JTS-SocketListener-55] - Error parsing integer value from header.
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at jextend.bg.q(bg.java:965)
    at jextend.eC.c(eC.java:480)
    at jextend.eC.run(eC.java:299)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2023-08-09 08:26:06.475 [SF] WARN  [JTS-SocketListener-55] - Error
twslaunch.jutils.SLogging$Warning: API client version is missing.
    at twslaunch.jutils.au.B(au.java:287)
    at jextend.eC.run(eC.java:302)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2023-08-09 08:26:06.481 [SF] INFO  [JTS-SocketListener-55] - State: STOP, IsAPI: NO
2023-08-09 08:26:06.481 [SF] ERROR [JTS-SocketListener-55] - Error parsing integer value from header.
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at jextend.bg.q(bg.java:965)
    at jextend.eC.c(eC.java:480)
    at jextend.eC.run(eC.java:299)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It seems to point out that a header with the API version is missing (though it not name the parameter) I tried to connect creating a python script and adding headers live `version: 1.0`, or `w: 1`, etc, but it didn't work

My config is:
[image]